# symmetric decryption throwing error

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, encryption-symmetric, openpgp

I'm working on adding the ability to decrypt a file encrypted using GPG & Symmetric Encryption.

However whenever it tries to get the private key data this exceptions keeps getting hit:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp.PgpPbeEncryptedData' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp.PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData'.

everywhere I look this is how you do it:

```
Stream inputStream = IoHelper.GetStream(inputData);
        PgpObjectFactory pgpFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream));
        PgpObject pgp = null;
        if (pgpFactory != null)
        {
            pgp = pgpFactory.NextPgpObject();
        }

        PgpEncryptedDataList encryptedData = null;
        if (pgp is PgpEncryptedDataList)
        {
            encryptedData = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgp;
        }
        else
        {
            encryptedData = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgpFactory.NextPgpObject();
        }

        Stream privateKeyStream = File.OpenRead(PrivateKeyOnlyPath);

        // find secret key
        PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpKeyRing = new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(privateKeyStream));
        PgpPrivateKey privateKey = null;

        foreach (PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pked in encryptedData.GetEncryptedDataObjects())
        {
            privateKey = FindSecretKey(pgpKeyRing, pked.KeyId, Password.ToCharArray());
            if (privateKey != null)
            {
                //pubKeyData = pked;
                break;
            }
        }
```

I'm referencing the code from [here](https://gist.github.com/dieseltravis/8323431)

I'm lost on why it's not working and not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hybrid Cryptosystems

The "normal" way of encryption in OpenPGP (which GnuPG implements) is hybrid encryption: public/private key cryptography for key management and encrypting a session key, and subsequently symmetric encryption using this session key of the actual data.

From what you write, it seems the public/private key cryptography step was omitted, and the session key instead generated using a passphrase, for example by using the command `gpg --symmetric`. You can determine how it was encrypted using `pgpdump`. Output for a symmetrically encrypted file looks like

```
Old: Symmetric-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet(tag 3)(13 bytes)
    New version(4)
    Sym alg - CAST5(sym 3)
    Iterated and salted string-to-key(s2k 3):
        Hash alg - SHA512(hash 10)
        Salt - 3b be 1b 03 64 c3 bb 7e 
        Count - 102400(coded count 105)
New: Symmetrically Encrypted Data Packet(tag 9)(26 bytes)
    Encrypted data [sym alg is specified in sym-key encrypted session key]
```

Especially consider the first line with the symmetric-key encrypted session key packet.

### What to do

I'm sorry I do not really know C#, and neither have worked with Bouncy Castle yet, so I cannot provide a ready-to-run solution. Moreover, the C# documentation seems to be more or less inexistent.

I'd guess you'll have to make use of the [`PgpPbeEncryptedData` class](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/openpgp/PgpPbeEncryptedData.cs), which seems to take an input stream and a passphrase and provides the decrypted information as an output stream. There is an [example for the Java Bouncy Castle package](https://gist.github.com/dwelch2344/6986219), which will probably be very similar and mostly boils down to

```
byte[] decryptedAgainByteArray = ByteArrayHandler.decrypt(encryptedAgain, PASS.toCharArray());
```